# Как сделать адаптивную вёрстку?

Tags: css, media-queries

Сделал адаптивность пользуясь инструментами хром , то есть отображал сайт как будто на мобильном устройстве 
Сделал адаптивность для каждого из устройств
Начал тестить - а на самих дейвайсах ситуация другая 
Как я понял , там например для яблока 6-7-8 разрешение 375-667 это без учёта окна браузера

И было бы без проблем , если сайт был с обычным скроллом, но тут постраничный скролл и каждая страница помещается внутрь окна браузера, а не внутрь всего разрешения , то есть из-за строк браузера высота получается меньше 667рх

Что можно с этим сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Сделать вёрстку ещё адаптивнее и проверять её на реальных устройствах, потому что  в хруме на компьютере не учитывается , что в мобильном браузере есть хэйдер в самом приложении браузера. 
Вывод : нужно адаптировать под все разрешения экранов